# Accessing unknown 'view' component of a property

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I get an 'Accessing unknown 'view' component of a property' error, when I'm trying this:

```
if (self.newsViewController.view.superview == nil)
```

I have a synthesize and an import for NewsViewController. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is the type of newsViewController? Does NewsViewController extend UIViewController?

Comment: Yes, it does
    @interface newsViewController : UIViewController {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, SO won't let me comment on your post, but if that:

`@interface newsViewController : UIViewController {`

is actually copy & pasted, it might just be a typo (lowercase 'n' instead of uppercase in NewsViewController)?

Comment: yep, that did it! thanks!
I used newsViewController in the beginning. Than I changed the class name to NewsViewController, but only the files and not the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Another problem might be absence of import...

> http://shirishranjit.com/blog1/?p=132